# Microsoft Speech to Text with non-ASCII file names

Tags: c++, unicode, internationalization, azure-cognitive-services

I'm playing with the Microsoft Speech API and the sample code at https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/tree/master/samples/cpp/windows/console. The `SpeechContinuousRecognitionWithFile()` function in [`speech_recognition_samples.cpp`](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/blob/master/samples/cpp/windows/console/samples/speech_recognition_samples.cpp) is almost completely what I need.

Modifying this function, I replaced the name of the input file by that of another file which happened to be on my disk, `"Blutgefäße.wav"`. This resulted in a `std::range_error` exception in the `FromWavFileInput` call, which could only be fixed by renaming the file to `"Blutgefaesse.wav"`.

Is it expected behavior of this function to crash with international file names? Do I have to use a Unicode version of the API? If so, where do I find it?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to supply non-ASCII file names in UTF-8 coding:

`u8"Blutgefäße.wav"`

The transcript, by the way, is also UTF-8 encoded.